# Toggling graphics for high intensity situations

Tags: eve-online

So I'm a burglar, moving from system to system scanning down sites and wrecks and such. This morning I came upon a limited sleeper cache and didn't even bother to try to crack the last can because I know it says you only have 120 seconds to open it and get out before the radiation pods you. I currently run the game on a Surface pro 4 so I was wondering other than getting a gaming rig:

- Could I hot key a graphics drop for better speed?

**UPDATE**
So based on comments below, I think it's safe to say that asking for a recommended graphic level is subject to taste(that's what I get for cramming two questions in one). At this point, I've gone into the graphics and unchecked all the effects in the top middle column, which has had an affect on current gameplay, but has yet to be tested by me being found/webbed/scrammed/dunked. I still would like to see if anyone has a solution where graphics could be toggled via hotkey.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if Eve Online has this option but if it has an option similar to resolution downscaling that would be helpful to turn on since it temporary lowers your resolution when there are FPS drops. Again I am not sure Eve has this so I am not answering it just commenting.

Comment: "*What's a better graphic level setting overall for this particular tabtop*" Sorry, but we don't do recommendations.

Comment: @Nolonar: There's an empirical answer for system performance for a particular collection of hardware and an application. Unfortunately, I don't have it. But it is certainly testable.

Comment: @Ellesedil the testability is not the point.  The issue is it is purely subjective, opinionated, and totally useless 3 months down the line.

Comment: I guess the issue is that the asker has not mentioned any specific graphics benchmarks he'd like to hit? Like a target framerate?

Comment: If you're going to remove part of your question for consideration, then actually delete it instead of annotating it or explaining it away. If someone really cares what the question used to say, they can look at the edit history.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* if you have the map fullscreened, it won't draw the game environment around your ship. However, I couldn't confirm/deny that in a few minute's googling, but that did turn up [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20171001054148/https://eveinfo.net/wiki/inde~280.htm), which lists keyboard shortcuts for a few things.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no hotkey to swap between the two.

The closest thing to a solution I can come up with is making two different launcher profiles for your account, and swap over when you want to. Certainly not as easy as a hotkey, but might be faster or at least less tedious.